# Efficient query to get step duration from an event logs table in sql into an accumulating snapshot fact

Tags: mysql, sql-server, data-warehouse

This example was built in SQL Server 2016 but it should also apply to MySQL 8.X.

I have event logs data stored in a table  `fact_user_event_activity` with the following sample data:

```
event_date_key  user_key    step_key    session_id  event_timestamp
20140411        123         1           1000        2014-04-11 08:00:00.000
20140411        123         2           1000        2014-04-11 08:10:00.000
20140411        123         3           1000        2014-04-11 08:20:00.000
20140411        123         4           1000        2014-04-11 08:30:00.000
20140411        125         1           1001        2014-04-11 09:10:00.000
20140411        123         5           1000        2014-04-11 08:31:00.000
20140411        125         2           1001        2014-04-11 09:30:00.000
20140411        125         3           1001        2014-04-11 09:50:00.000  <-- 
20140411        125         3           1001        2014-04-11 09:51:00.000  <--
20140411        125         4           1001        2014-04-11 09:52:00.000
```

**Assumptions**:

- All incoming records by user_key are ordered by date. However records are not ordered by user_key. For example, take a look of user_key `125` on `2014-04-11 09:10:00.000`.
- Steps are predictable. This process will always contain 5 steps where the last step means **EXIT**
- Steps on the same session can be logged multiple times at different dates

**Expected**

What would be the most efficient way to query the following?

```
user_key     session_id    step_1_duration_mins    step_2_duration_mins     step_3_duration_mins    step_4_duration_mins
123             1000           10                         10                       10                    1
125             1001           20                         20                        2                 NULL
```

This will be used as an ETL query for an accumulating snapshot

**Setup**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS  [fact_user_event_activity]
;
CREATE TABLE [fact_user_event_activity] (
  [event_date_key] INT DEFAULT NULL,
  [user_key] BIGINT NOT NULL,
  [step_key] BIGINT NOT NULL,
  [session_id] BIGINT NOT NULL,
  [event_timestamp] datetime NOT NULL
)
;
INSERT INTO [fact_user_event_activity]
VALUES (20140411, 123, 1, 1000, N'2014-04-11 08:00:00'),
(20140411, 123, 2, 1000, N'2014-04-11 08:10:00'),
(20140411, 123, 3, 1000, N'2014-04-11 08:20:00'),
(20140411, 123, 4, 1000, N'2014-04-11 08:30:00'),
(20140411, 125, 1, 1001, N'2014-04-11 09:10:00'),
(20140411, 123, 5, 1000, N'2014-04-11 08:31:00'),
(20140411, 125, 2, 1001, N'2014-04-11 09:30:00'),
(20140411, 125, 3, 1001, N'2014-04-11 09:50:00'),
(20140411, 125, 3, 1001, N'2014-04-11 09:51:00'),
(20140411, 125, 4, 1001, N'2014-04-11 09:52:00'),
(20140411, 129, 1, 1005, N'2014-04-11 09:08:00'),
(20140411, 129, 2, 1005, N'2014-04-11 09:10:00'),
(20140411, 129, 3, 1005, N'2014-04-11 09:12:00'),
(20140411, 129, 3, 1005, N'2014-04-11 09:13:00'),
(20140411, 129, 4, 1005, N'2014-04-11 09:14:00'),
(20140411, 129, 5, 1005, N'2014-04-11 09:18:00')
;
```

**My attempt**

To easily understand the code I approached this in two steps:

1. Get every step's duration from the start (start of session)
2. Calculate the difference between every step's duration_from_start

This returns what I'm expecting but I'm sure that I might be over-complicating things and this will run against ~ 500 M records, so I was wondering if there is a better approach or if I'm missing something.

```
-- Step 1
-- to improve performance, use temp table instead of CTE
-- Use TIMESTAMPDIFF in MySQL instead of DATEDIFF
WITH durations_from_start_tmp AS
    (
    SELECT session_id, user_key, FIRST_VALUE(fuea.event_timestamp) OVER(PARTITION BY user_key, fuea.session_id ORDER BY fuea.event_timestamp) first_login,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY user_key, step_key, fuea.session_id ORDER BY fuea.event_timestamp) AS rnk,
    CASE WHEN step_key = 2 THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, FIRST_VALUE(fuea.event_timestamp) OVER(PARTITION BY user_key, fuea.session_id ORDER BY fuea.event_timestamp), fuea.event_timestamp) END AS step_1_duration_from_start,
    CASE WHEN step_key = 3 THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, FIRST_VALUE(fuea.event_timestamp) OVER(PARTITION BY user_key, fuea.session_id ORDER BY fuea.event_timestamp), fuea.event_timestamp) END AS step_2_duration_from_start,
    CASE WHEN step_key = 4 THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, FIRST_VALUE(fuea.event_timestamp) OVER(PARTITION BY user_key, fuea.session_id ORDER BY fuea.event_timestamp), fuea.event_timestamp) END AS step_3_duration_from_start,
    CASE WHEN step_key = 5 THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, FIRST_VALUE(fuea.event_timestamp) OVER(PARTITION BY user_key, fuea.session_id ORDER BY fuea.event_timestamp), fuea.event_timestamp) END AS step_4_duration_from_start
    FROM [fact_user_event_activity] fuea
    --WHERE event_timestamp > watermark --for incremental load
    )

-- Step 2
SELECT user_key, session_id, SUM(step_1_duration_from_start) AS step_1_duration_mins,
 SUM(step_2_duration_from_start) - SUM(step_1_duration_from_start) AS step_2_duration_mins ,
 SUM(step_3_duration_from_start) - SUM(step_2_duration_from_start) AS step_3_duration_mins ,
 SUM(step_4_duration_from_start) - SUM(step_3_duration_from_start) AS step_4_duration_mins
 FROM durations_from_start_tmp
 -- deals with repeated steps
 WHERE rnk = 1
 GROUP BY  user_key, session_id
```

**References**

This might not be relevant to get the answer but just in case you're not familiar with Data Modeling concepts

[Accumulating Snapshots Definition](https://www.kimballgroup.com/data-warehouse-business-intelligence-resources/kimball-techniques/dimensional-modeling-techniques/accumulating-snapshot-fact-table/)

Comment: iam very much tempted this say this is offtopic https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic here and better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic.. As you claimed the code works, stackoverflow is more meant for bugged code..

Comment: But to answer your question as you need to compare between the current and "first" record  using a window function is most likely the best performing method.

Comment: @RaymondNijland much appreciated, I've been looking everywhere for examples on this kind of analytical problems and I thought this  was "a specific programming problem"  as it looks like the "Accumulating snapshots" are a very common practice , and given that this was my first attempt using these facts I was concerned on the complexity, and probably a missing unknown window function.

Comment: Since you don't appear to actually be using the window functions in your final select, perhaps it would be better to skip using them. For example, you can just select the min value for each step (e.g. `step_1_timestamp = MIN(CASE WHEN step_key = 1 THEN event_timestamp END), step_2_timestamp = MIN(CASE WHEN step_key = 2...`) then get the duration of each step by doing a datediff like `step_1_duration = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, step_1_timestamp, step_2_timestamp)`. With an index on the columns you're grouping by and step_key/event_timestamp, this seems better than using (unnecessary) window functions.

Comment: @ZLKthanks, I think I get it, would you put this approach as a an answer so I can visualize your whole idea an of course vote it up or even mark as an answer if this happens to be the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So one approach you might take is adding an index (assuming you can add one) such as:

`CREATE INDEX [SomeIndexName] ON [fact_user_event_activity] (user_key, session_id, step_key, event_timestamp);`

(Or you could just do an include on step_key, event_timestamp if you're concerned about the size of the index on 500m rows.)

Then skip using the window functions with a query such as the following:

```
SELECT user_key,
       session_id,
       step_1_duration = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, step_1_timestamp, step_2_timestamp),
       step_2_duration = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, step_2_timestamp, step_3_timestamp),
       step_3_duration = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, step_3_timestamp, step_4_timestamp),
       step_4_duration = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, step_4_timestamp, step_5_timestamp)
FROM 
(
    SELECT user_key, session_id,
           step_1_timestamp = MIN(CASE WHEN step_key = 1 THEN event_timestamp END),
           step_2_timestamp = MIN(CASE WHEN step_key = 2 THEN event_timestamp END),
           step_3_timestamp = MIN(CASE WHEN step_key = 3 THEN event_timestamp END),
           step_4_timestamp = MIN(CASE WHEN step_key = 4 THEN event_timestamp END),
           step_5_timestamp = MIN(CASE WHEN step_key = 5 THEN event_timestamp END)
    FROM fact_user_event_activity
    GROUP BY user_key, session_id
) AS T;
```

(Which would theoretically do just an index scan without requiring any sorts.)

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for, it makes more sense. My thought process was on the same route but I did not need to calculate the durations from start =) this is way more simple.